# Function dependent on the value in the rows in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, sapply, standard-deviation

I would like the function to depend on the `sd` value for each product in the data frame. So not to enter a constant `sd` value in the function, because each product has a different `sd`.

```
df <- data.frame(Product = c("A", "B"), 
                 Oct = c(33, 23),
                 Nov = c(23, 26),
                 SD = c(1, 5))

rand_vect_cont <- function(N, M, sd) {
  vec <- rnorm(N, M/N, sd)
  vec / sum(vec) * M
}

sapply(unlist(df[2:3]), rand_vect_cont, N = 4, df$SD)
```

I want to create a new table whose columns will be the sum of individual elements in the data frame. Here is example with constant sd:

```
> sapply(unlist(df[2:3]), rand_vect_cont, N = 4, sd = 1)
         Oct1     Oct2     Nov1     Nov2
[1,] 7.492679 5.285553 4.716102 6.177153
[2,] 8.499570 6.008897 6.339937 6.638079
[3,] 9.301981 6.617405 5.262105 6.235205
[4,] 7.705770 5.088145 6.681856 6.949563
```

Comment: When you `unlist` you are regarding it as single vector.

Comment: My question is that don't you want to do this for each Product separately `split(df[-1], df$Product)`

Comment: Yes, it can be separated like that

Comment: Do you need `sapply(unlist(df[2:3]), Vectorize(rand_vect_cont), N = 4, sd = df$SD)`

Comment: too many rows, it should be 4, as in my example

Comment: Yes, please check my solution in the post.  with `sapply`, it coerces to a single column, `lapply` will show the structure correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `set.seed()` inside your function for reproducible result.

```
df <- data.frame(Product = c("A", "B"), 
                 Oct = c(33, 23),
                 Nov = c(23, 26),
                 SD = c(1, 5))
rand_vect_cont <- function(N, M, sd) {
  set.seed(1); 
  vec <- rnorm(N, M/N, sd)
  vec / sum(vec) * M
}
```

**Data table solution**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df <- melt(df, id.vars = c("Product", "SD"), variable.name = "month")
df[, rand_vect_cont(4, value, SD), by = .(Product, SD, month)]

#     Product SD month        V1
# 1:        A  1   Oct  7.551047
# 2:        A  1   Oct  8.353440
# 3:        A  1   Oct  7.343861
# 4:        A  1   Oct  9.751653
# 5:        B  5   Oct  2.449044
# 6:        B  5   Oct  6.238516
# 7:        B  5   Oct  1.470566
# 8:        B  5   Oct 12.841873
# 9:        A  1   Nov  5.053925
# 10:       A  1   Nov  5.853014
# 11:       A  1   Nov  4.847592
# 12:       A  1   Nov  7.245469
# 13:       B  5   Nov  3.174316
# 14:       B  5   Nov  6.992176
# 15:       B  5   Nov  2.188509
# 16:       B  5   Nov 13.644999
```

**Compare with your code - `base R`:**

```
df <- data.frame(Product = c("A", "B"), 
                     Oct = c(33, 23),
                     Nov = c(23, 26),
                     SD = c(1, 5))

sapply(unlist(df[2:3]), rand_vect_cont, N = 4, sd = 1)
#          Oct1     Oct2     Nov1     Nov2
# [1,] 7.551047 5.053925 5.053925 5.802832
# [2,] 8.353440 5.853014 5.853014 6.603176
# [3,] 7.343861 4.847592 4.847592 5.596175
# [4,] 9.751653 7.245469 7.245469 7.997818

sapply(unlist(df[2:3]), rand_vect_cont, N = 4, sd = 5)
#           Oct1      Oct2      Nov1      Nov2
# [1,]  4.883302  2.449044  2.449044  3.174316
# [2,]  8.748246  6.238516  6.238516  6.992176
# [3,]  3.885336  1.470566  1.470566  2.188509
# [4,] 15.483117 12.841873 12.841873 13.644999
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Map`

```
do.call(cbind, Map(function(x, y) sapply(x, rand_vect_cont, N = 4, sd = y),
          asplit(as.matrix(df[2:3]), 1), df$SD))
 #     Oct      Nov       Oct       Nov
#[1,] 7.551047 5.053925  2.449044  3.174316
#[2,] 8.353440 5.853014  6.238516  6.992176
#[3,] 7.343861 4.847592  1.470566  2.188509
#[4,] 9.751653 7.245469 12.841873 13.644999
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -c(Product, SD), names_to = "month") %>% 
   group_by(Product, month, SD) %>% 
   summarise(value = list(rand_vect_cont(4, value, SD)))  %>% 
   unnest(c(value))
# A tibble: 16 x 4
# Groups:   Product, month [4]
#   Product month    SD value
#   <fct>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A       Nov       1  5.05
# 2 A       Nov       1  5.85
# 3 A       Nov       1  4.85
# 4 A       Nov       1  7.25
# 5 A       Oct       1  7.55
# 6 A       Oct       1  8.35
# 7 A       Oct       1  7.34
# 8 A       Oct       1  9.75
# 9 B       Nov       5  3.17
#10 B       Nov       5  6.99
#11 B       Nov       5  2.19
#12 B       Nov       5 13.6 
#13 B       Oct       5  2.45
#14 B       Oct       5  6.24
#15 B       Oct       5  1.47
#16 B       Oct       5 12.8
```

EDIT: Using the same seed showed in @Sathish's post

Comment: I need the unlist function because I have to count every element in the data frame.

Comment: @Elia Are you doing this for each 'Product', ie. by row, in that case, the second option should work

Comment: but it doesn't work properly, I want to have four columns because I have to break down every element in the data frame into its sum

Comment: The sum in the columns does not match the values in the data frame.

Comment: @Elia But that condition was not in your post.  I read `would like the function to depend on the sd value for each product in the data frame.`

Comment: I didn't know how to name the subject correctly, I added an example with a fixed sd value.

Comment: Why are there 8 columns? They should be 4 as in my example.

Comment: @Elia Not clear though.  You want to have two values of `sd` .  Each column is for the different sd.

Comment: @Elia Let's say if you want only 4 values, then which one will map to each `SD` value?

Comment: Product A has its value and product B has its own

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203703/discussion-between-elia-and-akrun).